# Simplify $z^7\div z^{-x}\cdot z^{-y^{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The correct answer from 4 possible choices is $z^{7+x-y^{2}}$ however I get $z^{7+x+y^{2}}$

$x^a\cdot x^b=x^{a+b}$

$z^7\div z^{-x}\cdot z^{-y^{2}}$  $\Rightarrow$  $z^7\div z^{-x-y^{2}}$

$x^a\div x^b=x^{a-b}$

$z^7\div z^{-x-y^{2}}$  $\Rightarrow$  $z^{7-(-x-y^{2})}$  $\Rightarrow$  $z^{7+x+y^{2}}$

Comment: This is more of a question on multiplication order.

Comment: Is it $\displaystyle \frac{z^7}{z^{-x}}\cdot{z^{-y^2}}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{z^7}{z^{-x}\cdot{z^{-y^2}}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in multiplication and division, you start from the left. Thus, we should calculate $z^7 \div z^{-x}=z^{7+x}$ then we should calculated $z^{7+x} \times z^{-y^2}=z^{7+x-y^2}$.

What you have calculated is what the result would be if the problem was asking for $z^7\div (z^{-x}\cdot z^{-y^{2}})$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication doesn't go inside division: $$a:b\cdot c = (a:b)\cdot c$$
so:
$$z^7 : z^{-x}\cdot z^{-y^{2}} = z^{7 - (-x) + (-y^2)} = z^{7+x-y^2}$$